# CSS background (svg/base64) gets stretched horizontally upon orientation change

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am trying to make a Phonegap application using HTML/CSS3/Jquery and JS. 
I have made certain divs which have a background image (a css embedded base-64 encoded svg image). However, this background image gets stretched upon device orientation change. (from portrait to landscape).

i have set the following css properties:

```
#top-bar #settings {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[image_data]) no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-position: center;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
}
```

I have also observed that this behaviour is not visible in my desktop browsers or in certain other Android phones. My phone (where i see the problem is a Galaxy s3 rooted with cyanogen 10.1.3)

Is there any way to stop this from happening? I want the background to look same in any conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a single styling for both portrait/landscape orientations, that refer to viewport size in a relative way.

I would use media queries to detect orientation, and define specific styling to perform a fine tuning of the background look according to it.

Something like (check actual syntax):

```
@media (orientation: portrait){
  #top-bar #settings {
    /* Portrait styling */
  }
}

@media (orientation: landscape){
  #top-bar #settings {
    /* Landscape styling */
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the relative attributes.

```
background-size: 50% 50%;

width: 10%;
height: 100%;
```

Those give you different total sizes if the screens width & height is changing without keeping the aspect ratio!

Just keep the background width size at 50%. If no second size is set, it has the initial value "auto", which keeps the aspect ratio of the image.

```
background-size: 50%;
```

This should solve your problem.